# If $\sin(a)+2\sin(b)+3\sin(c)=\cos(a)+2\cos(b)+3\cos(c)=0$ then find $\sin(b+c)+2\sin(c+a)+3\sin(a+b)$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

If $\sin(a)+2\sin(b)+3\sin(c)=\cos(a)+2\cos(b)+3\cos(c)=0$ then find $\sin(b+c)+2\sin(c+a)+3\sin(a+b)$

I think euler's theorem and De moivre's theorem are to be used

Comment: Welcome to Math SE!  Please [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3981500/edit) your question to include your own thoughts on the problem.

Comment: You can cheat and let $a=b=0, c=\pi$.

Comment: This is not cheating. It's an example of the "lazy mathematician" at work. Think to the professor MacLaurin who remained famous among posterity for having substituted zero in Taylor's formula

Comment: @Raffaele did Maclaurin substitute $x=0$ into Taylor's formula or did Taylor generalise Maclaurin's formula?

Comment: @A-LevelStudent I was kidding, of course. It looks like my joke was not so far from reality, tho. "Maclaurin received credit for his use of the series, and the Taylor series expanded around 0 is sometimes known as the *Maclaurin series*" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colin_Maclaurin#Contributions_to_mathematics

Answer (score 0):

[The original problem has 2 parts I am sharing them both](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MtEq.jpg)

[This is our required answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abZrp.jpg)

The images are the links in blue please do have a look

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not an answer...

Comment: @newQOpenGLWidget should i type the whole answer

Comment: Yes, you should.

Comment: Especially because some people sort by unanswered questions only, and so they may skip your question.